# How to rewrite MAVEN POM.XML COMBINE.SELF

Tags: xml, maven

I was just given an existing project to work on, that uses Maven. I am completely unfamiliar with Maven.

We're using Maven 3.2.2. The POM.XML file in the project was created in version 2.1.1.

Here's the code I need to rewrite:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>   
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration combine.self="override">
                    <packagingIncludes>WEB-INF/lib/slauthentication-svc*.jar,WEB-INF/*.*,WEB-INF/classes/**/*.*,WEB-INF/flex/*.*,WEB-INF/cxf/*.*,WEB-INF/wsdl/*.*,META-INF/**/*.*,Vision/**/*.*,console/**/*.*,Template/*.*</packagingIncludes>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>src/main/webapp/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>               
        </plugins>          
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

The line I have to change is the combine.self-"override" line. Putting the combine.self in the configuration tag is no longer valid in 3.2.2.

Basically, I need to change it, but I can't quite figure how it needs to be changed.

I found the following code snippet on the web:

```
<configuration>
    <items combine.children="append">
        <!-- combine.children="merge" is the default -->
        <item>child-1</item>
    </items>
    <properties combine.self="override">
        <!-- combine.self="merge" is the default -->
        <childKey>child</childKey>
    </properties>
</configuration>
```

The trouble is, this is as clear as mud to me. I get that I need to add a properties tag, but where in my code above would I put it?

This is for a child project.

Thanks for any help you fellows can give.

Comment: "The line I have to change is the combine.self-"override" line. That is no longer valid in 3.2.2." It should still be valid in Maven 3.2.2; please provide more details about what's failing.

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't as clear as I thought I was. Combine-Self is allowed, but not where it's at above. I'll edit to make it clearer.

Comment: "We're using Maven 3.2.2. The POM.XML file in the project was created in version 2.1.1." These don't correspond to [versions of Maven](https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html). Do you have the actual versions? (`mvn --version`)

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you guys. They wanted this thing in production right away. I got the version 2.1.1 from the pom.xml file, as you can see in the code above. The maven installer our network guys gave me said 3.2.2, but the actual version number is 3.2.1. But, praise be, I've been moved off of this project, onto a couple of hot ticket problems that I actually know how to fix. Thanks, all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A bad question asked when I was, quite frankly, out of my depth in a project I didn't have the background to handle in the timeframe required.